# Monitor webpage changes

Tags: javascript, php, html

Suppose there is a website on internet which shows Indian share market price. And price of share is changing every second.

**This site provides no api support**

How can i continuously track this price and update to user when price goes above a specified limit.

I am beginner please help me how to start and where to start

All the process should be on server not from my phone/pc

I am beginner please help me how to start.

Comment: To start : check [this](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.file-get-contents.php) . Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can setup a web scrapper that fetches the page on a periodical basis with the help of a background job, you may begin with PHP and Cron.